# Django python manage.py runserver TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, typeerror

'''
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/league/`

Django Version: 4.1.2
Python Version: 3.10.0
Installed Applications:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/km/Projects/tournament/Worldchamps/champ_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

Exception Type: TypeError at /league/
Exception Value: 'dict' object is not callable
```

'''

Comment: Can't help you if you don't show the code.

Comment: Show the view that `/league/` is pointing to and might as well show the view. more than likely you are just treating a dictionary like a Django object somewhere

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, let me add more details. Thanks